# How do I enable file extensions for all files?

Tags: onedrive

I just created a SkyDrive account and was quite confused that the file extensions are hidden for certain file types:

[image]
<sup>`ntbtlog` is actually `ntbtlog.txt`</sup>

I looked around the menus but didn't spot an option to enable/disable this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [April 2012 answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/skydrive-files/filename-extensions-in-skydrive/01470a21-9d19-4293-9a64-50632c9f2a67?msgId=1cc129cd-0322-472f-963a-b9938549a570&page=1) from Jeff Steinbok, the MS SkyDrive dev lead, file extensions are visible only for file types that SkyDrive doesn't internally support. Internally supported file types do not show extensions by default.

Another answer to the same question suggested that users file a [feature request](https://feedback.live.com/default.aspx?productkey=wlfolders).

In summary, this feature isn't currently available.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that Google Drive, DropBox, SugarSync and really every other cloud storage service does support this...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround.  Using the Search Field on the Onedrive page, search for the file extension to get a list of all files with that extension.  EX:  if you are looking for Photoshop files, enter: *.psd in the search field.

While this doesn't necessarily help with all file management needs, it can help find file types until Microsoft decides to stop annoying its users.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this workaround, which solves the problem for files you upload yourself. Add the file extension twice, for example rename `report.doc` to `report.doc.doc`. Microsoft will suppress the final `.doc` but leave the first one as it is part of the file name.